# How can I enter the following batch file code directly on the command line

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I would like to enter the following batch file code directly on the command line:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "type=.jpg"
set "source=c:\"
set "dest=c:\AllPics"

for /r "%source%" %%f in ("*%type%") do (
  for %%d in ("%dest%\%%~nf*") do (
    set /a count+=1
  )

  set "source=%%f"
  set "dest=%dest%\%%~nf"
  xcopy "!source!" "!dest!!count!%type%*"
  set count=
)
```

When I enter the code in the command line, unfortunately, the file can not be found with the error messages as below. How can I fix it?

[image]

```
set "type=.jpg" & set "source=C:\" & set "dest=c:\AllPics"
for /r "%source%" %f in ("*%type%") do ( for %d in ("%dest%\%%~nf*") do (set /a count+=1)
set "source=%f" & set "dest=%dest%\%%~nf" & xcopy "!source!" "!dest!!count!%type%*" & set count=)


File not found - !source!
0 File(s) copied

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Comment: You need to enter this into a text file and then run that file from the prompt.  You can't enter it directly on the command line.  Thats why they call it a batch ***file***.  You *can* use the windows notepad, but I suggest for a free lightweight editor.. try [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/). ;)  Good luck.

Comment: Please understand that what is in the scope has been answered, changes/additions that imply adding features not present in the original edition may be misunderstood, and prejudice responses/respondents already added ...

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand how memory works on the command interpreter in order to run individual lines and get it to have the same outcome as the batch file.

I don't know how the memory works and so I won't try to tell you how to run this, but merely to say that for most Batch scripts you cannot simply paste lines of a script one at a time into the prompt and get the same outcome.

Running a batch file handles the storage and passing along of information between the various parts of the script, and this is why you ought to run it as a cohesive script unless there are truly compelling reasons not to.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Good luck

Comment: But files that duplicate names are not copied

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define `this` to use `this` in `this` form, or that way ... so, if you remove your variables, you will have an easier way to doing what you want

I'm not 100% sure what exactly you want to do, but your commands suggest that you want to copy all files recursively to your `c:` drive, adding the amount of `.jpg`  files present in your source folders under the destination name.

For do it in command line:

```
for /r C:\ %f in ("*.jpg")do for /f %d in ('"dir/b "%~dpf*.jpg"|find /v /c """')do copy /y "%~f" "C:\AllPics\%~nf%~d.jpg"
```

To prevent this execution also take actions on your destination folder:

```
for /f tokens^=*useback %f in (`"where /r C:\ "*.jpg"|findstr /bvil "C:\AllPics""`)do for /f %d in ('"dir/b "%~dpf*.jpg"|find /v /c """')do copy /y "%~f" "C:\AllPics\%~nf%~d.jpg"
```

**Obs.:**  If I misunderstood your question, please let me know, thanks...

The `xcopy` command will ask you for each file, if is a file or directory when your command run, so you can change to `copy`...

Comment: Thank you for answering. Good luck

Comment: Yes correctly noticed

Comment: @john Welcome to SU! Good to know! Thank you too...

Comment: But files with the same name are not copied

Comment: @john  copy /y overwrite file if exist in target folder....

Comment: @john this probably only happens if you run this command more then 1x

Comment: I have two files with the same name in two different folders, but only one of them is copied, but when I ran the file batch, it copied both files by renaming . for example c:\a\1.jpg  c:\b\1.jpg  copy  C:\AllPics\1.jpg  C:\AllPics\10.jpg

Comment: @john forgive, it's possible, but it's out of scope... And, 
both (and more) are copied too, but because they are of the same name, it results in seconds/thirds being overwritten in the first ...

Comment: you must forgive me for asking too many questions

Comment: @john yes, no problem, you are welcomed here, and maybe you gonna needed, open a new question. So sorry my limited english